# Real variable lemma

Tags: calculus, integration, derivatives

Someone can help with the following lemma?

> **Lemma:** Let $\theta'(r)\geq0,\theta(r)>0$ and $\dfrac{\theta'(r)}{\theta(r)}$ decreasing for $r>0$. Then 
>   $$\frac{\displaystyle\int^r_0\theta'(s)\,ds}{\displaystyle\int^r_0\theta(s)\,ds}$$
>    is decreasing.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'll assume $\theta(r)$ doesn't vanish in $[0, \infty)$. Now for every $\displaystyle 0 \leq s < r$, $\displaystyle \frac{\theta'(r)}{\theta(r)} \leq \frac{\theta'(s)}{\theta(s)}$. Cross multiply and integrate from $0$ to $r$ to get $\displaystyle \theta'(r) \int_0^r \theta(s) ds - \theta(r) \int_0^r \theta'(s)ds \leq 0$. But this means, $\displaystyle \frac{d}{dr}$ of your quotient of integrals is $\leq 0$.

Comment: You are the GUY!!! Thanks!